# How to adjust this number input field's format to either USD (period as separator) or COP (comma as separator) dynamically in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

The table has an input field, which, depending on the `currency` passed, it's supposed to have either a comma or a period as decimal separator.

I have tried setting it initally to either `lang="es"` or `lang="en"`, but it doesn't change.

I'd appreciate a little help!

```js
function add_to_total(el, currency) {
currency = 'es'
  let rowTotal = 0;
  let currencyFormat = currency == 'en' ?  Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD",
  }) : Intl.NumberFormat("es-CO", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "COP",
  }) 


  if (el) {
    let parent = $(el).closest('tr'),
      price = parent.find('.price').val(),
      qty = parent.find('.qty').val();

    if (price == '' || qty == '') {
      alert('Please make sure that the price and metros are informed correctly.');
      return;
    }
    rowTotal = (qty * price).toFixed(2);
    parent.find('.total_price').html(currencyFormat.format(rowTotal));
  } else {
    $("#tableRows tr").each(function() {
      price = parseFloat($(this).find('.qty').val());
      qty = parseFloat($(this).find('.price').val());
      if (price && qty) {
        rowTotal = (price * qty).toFixed(2);
        $(this).find('.total_price').text(currencyFormat.format(rowTotal));
      }
    });
  }

  var gridTotal = 0;
  $(".total_price").each(function(index, item) {
    var val = parseFloat($(this).html().replace(/[$,]/g, ''));
    if (isNaN(val)) val = 0;
    gridTotal += val;
  });
  $('.total').html(currencyFormat.format(gridTotal.toFixed(2)));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:7%">Precio/m (USD)</th>
      <th style="width:8%">Metros (m)</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Precio Total sin IVA (COP)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableRows">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this);"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="0" onchange="add_to_total(this);'=""></td>
      <td class=" total_price"><strong>0.00</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" class="price" name="numberInputs" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this);"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="0" onchange="add_to_total(this)"></td>
      <td class="total_price"><strong>0.00</strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="totalTitle" colspan="8" align="right"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
      <td id="totalValue" class="total">0.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```